# Why $P_1\neq P_1P_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> **Question:** If $P_1,P_2$ are distinct prime ideals of an artinian ring, why is it that $P_1\neq P_1P_2$?

I know that prime ideals of an artinian ring are maximal, but still, I can't see why $P_1=P_1P_2$ is impossible. I suspect it must be very easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $P_1P_2 \subseteq P_2$, so if $P_1 = P_1P_2$ then by maximality $P_1 = P_2$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you get  $P_1=P_1P_2\subsetneq P_2$ , so $P_1$ is not maximal.